# Live credentials in new PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, paypal

Our iPad app has been processing payments successfully in sandbox mode using v1.0.4 of the iOS SDK.  Now we have received our live credentials.  However, using these we only ever see a generic alert "There was a problem communicating with the PayPal servers."

As far as I can tell from the docs and sample app, you just need to change the clientID and receiverEmail to the live id and account email, and set the environment to PayPalEnvironmentProduction (or not set it).  I've tried calling prepareForPaymentUsingClientId and not calling it.

Has anyone successfully used the new SDK in live mode? Are there any undocumented requirements? I've submitted support requests but have not gotten any response.

Thanks.

Comment: This issue is still happening

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a system issue and we are working on it. There will be a message posted on https://www.paypal.com/sitestatus so you can keep checking to see when it is resolved.

**edit:** This should be resolved as of ~ 04:12 AM GMT (31/03/2013).

Comment: I got this issue again here ... "We're Sorry - There was a problem communication with the PayPal servers" - Sandbox environment is working well. Live environment is getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

sorry my fault - in case someone has version 1.0.4 and still getting that alert. Go back to you paypal dev center and complete registration. Once you complete reg. it will give you a live key that you have to replace.